# In KSH I'm trying to grep for string inside a file name and if there move to a different directory

Tags: grep, ksh, file-moving

I've got a script that takes all files with extension of `.123` Some of them start with `ABC` others start with `XYZ`.  I want to take all the files that have `XYZ` in the PREFIX and move them to a different directory.
For example, `XYZothertext.123` and `ABCothertext.123` both come in to a directory `/test`  I want to evaluate if any file contains `XYZ` in the name and if so, move it to `/TEMP` instead of `/test`. AND delete from original folder.

```
if grep -q XYZ "$*.123"; then
   mv *.ABC /TEMP
fi
```

This is probably terribly incorrect. But I'm learning.

Comment: So what's the question? It sounds like you need to take a look up how to do an if statement in your chosen scripting language. Do you have any existing code written that you can share with us?

Comment: You are looking for the glob pattern `XYZ*.123`

Comment: Scott, The rest of the script was written by a pro...I'm just adding to the code with this attempt. I understand if statements in theory, and can pick apart what they are typically doing. The question is, can someone share an example of how to write this (in KSH)?  I often learn by example and reverse engineering.

Comment: I've written this thus far: ### Check for UB9 files and move to /ub835 if found
cd $ub9dir
if grep -q UB9* "$*.835"; then
   mv UB9* /UB9Files
 fi

Comment: `grep` is for matching patterns on its input or in file content, not for matching file names. You want a glob as @glennjackman said. Your command will look something like `mv XYZ*.123 /TEMP`. If you need to do it recursively then you may want `find` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
mv XYZ*123 /TEMP
mv ABC*123 /test
```